# Does FTP connections and transfers made from C# WinForms web application are counted in IIS7 bandwidth logs?

Tags: iis-7, bandwidth, website, windows

does FTP connections and transfers made from C# WinForms web application are counted in IIS bandwidth logs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connections will show up in the ftp server's log, regardless of what client made the connections.  That is, obviously, so long as logging is enabled on the server.  FTP client logs will be created depending on how the client is written.

Comment: Yep. In FTP server logs for sure but I will not have access to them. I as a hoster have only logs from IIS7 and I'm wondering if transfer made from inside web application (HTTP requests / FTP transfers etc.) are logged by IIS.

Comment: They'll only be logged if your application is written in such a way that they are logged.  Your IIS7 server will not know about any outgoing requests that your application makes, only incoming requests from outside of your system.